# flutter dart try catch error, when an error occur, the code in try block still run to the end then catch error happen?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I not sure why when there is an error/exception the code in try block still finish running then catch error happened? shouldn't it just jump to catch block instead of finishing code in try then go to catch error?

```
flutter: no error
flutter: error
flutter: PlatformException(Error 5, FIRFirestoreErrorDomain, No document to update: projects/dev-taskvsme/databases/(default)/documents/taskBank/Fark)
```

This is the error on firebase

> PlatformException(Error 5, FIRFirestoreErrorDomain, No document to
>   update:
>   projects/dev-taskvsme/databases/(default)/documents/taskBank/Fark)

```
try {
  final response = await colRef.document(docID).updateData(data).timeout(Duration(seconds: _timeout));
  print("no error");
  return RequestHandler.isSuccess({});
} catch(err) {
  print("error");
  print(err);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the answer?

Comment: Are you *absolutely certain* that you're observing what you think you are?  It looks to me that your code got executed two separate times, succeeding the first time and failing the second.  You should put a `print` statement when entering the `try` block too.

Comment: @jamesdlin yes you are right! it ran 2 times! holyshit. thanks man!